# Adaptive Cards nuget package to be used for bot frameworks version 4 C#

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am not sure about the nuget package to be included for the adaptive cards in version 4 bot application which is being migrated from version 3. The options available are AdaptiveCards nuget package and Microsoft.AdaptiveCards(both by Microsoft). In version 3 we had adaptiveCards(by AdaptiveCards) which we were using.

We were using the following nuget package for adaptive cards(by AdaptiveCards) [Adaptive cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Teo4O.png) in our version 3 application, kindly help me with the nuget package to be used for version 4 of same application so that the changes to be done in the existing code could be minimal and time saving.

When I add the suggested package in v4 aplication and the adaptive cards methods, I get the error 'AdaptiveCards is obselete. Please use the overload that accepts the version parameter and specify the version your card requires.'

[image: Nuget Package used]

One of the methods from our Adaptive Cards Class:

```
     //Create an adaptive card to show the SharePoint search result      


       public static Attachment SPSearchAdapativecard(string title, string summery, string actionUrl)
    {
        summery = summery.Replace("<c0>", "**");
        summery = summery.Replace("</c0>", "**");
        summery = summery.Replace("<ddd/>", "...");

        AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard()
        {
            Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
            {

                    new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                    {
                       Text = title,
                       Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                       Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium,
                       Wrap=false,
                       Separator = false,
                       Color= AdaptiveTextColor.Accent
                    },
                     new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                    {
                       Text = summery,
                       Wrap=true,
                       Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Small
                    },
            },
            Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
            {
                new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction()
                {
                    Id = "moreInfoBtn",
                    Title= "More Info",
                    Url= new Uri(actionUrl)
                }
            }
        };
        // Create the attachment with adapative card.  
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = card
        };
        return attachment;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure about the nuget package to be included for the adaptive cards in version 4 bot application which is being migrated from version 3. The options available are AdaptiveCards nuget package and Microsoft.AdaptiveCards(both by Microsoft). In version 3 we had adaptiveCards(by AdaptiveCards) which we were using.

Comment: it might be a good idea to update your question with the information you just added, and be as clear as possible

Comment: I have edited my question, it must be fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `Microsoft.AdaptiveCards` package on Nuget.org ([here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AdaptiveCards/)), you will see that it is old and `Deprecated`. Last update is 17/09/2017

Then on `AdaptiveCards` on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/): versions are from a few days ago, and initial version is 24/10/2017: this package is the successor of the previously mentioned package.

Moreover, if you look at the Bot Builder Samples on GitHub, there is one for Adaptive Cards [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards).

Look at the referenced packages:

[image: packages]

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. I understand that I will have to use the second one you have mentioned AdaptiveCards - version 1.1.2. Also, please help me with the changes that I will have to implement on the C# code side.

Comment: It is still the same package. Look at the sample first please, I can’t help more without more context

Comment: I have edited my question and added a method from our version 3 code. When I add the suggested package in v4 aplication and the adaptive cards methods, I get the error 'AdaptiveCards is obselete. Please use the overload that accepts the version parameter and specify the version your card requires.'

Comment: So use the overload. It's open-source by the way, so you can directly have a look (even with your error message which can be easily found): https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/master/source/dotnet/Library/AdaptiveCards/AdaptiveCard.cs#L44

Comment: yes @Nicolas R, your suggestion of using the overload helped. I am now able to reuse the existing class. Thanks a lot!!